# Is there a way in angular2 that a template is selected based on the device

Tags: mobile, angular, angular-template

I would like to have 1 per device template for views in angular2 and for some views there may be 1 for all the devices. Is it possible in angular2 based on the browser user-agent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plans but it has yet to be decided if it will actually be implemented.
Currently you can use media queries and for example `ngSwitch` to show different parts of a view depending on the device or screen dimensions.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6328
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1239
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? (Just I know you are active member and know more about changes)

Comment: These plans were dropped. I'm not aware of anything in that direction, but I wasn't able to follow Angular that closely in recent months.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS @imports with media queries for this.

All you need to do is to create a separate CSS file for each device and then import it in your template style.

Example:

Angular2 component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `...`,
  styleUrls: ['./style.css']
})
```

In `style.css`:

```
@import url("device1.css") screen and (min-width: 300px);
@import url("device2.css") screen and (min-width: 800px);
```

And then the device-specific styles in device1.css and device2.css.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import for details to CSS @imports.

Comment: He asked about template switching not CSS switching. What you proposed could be easily achieved with media queries alone without the @import statement.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative it's using [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) package
with the

[fxHide API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxHide-API) and [fxShow API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API)

**Example**

```
<div fxShow fxHide.xs="false" fxHide.lg="true"> ... </div>
```

**When the activated breakpoint is:**

- `xl`, then fallback to the default fxShow; so the div is shown
- `lg`, then the div is hidden (since the value === 'true')
- `md`, then fallback to the default fxShow;so the div is shown
- `sm`, then fallback to the default fxShow; so the div is shown
- `xs`, then the div is shown (since the value === 'false')

**This is the list with the breackpoint**

[image]

or using the [ObservableMedia](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia)

**Example**

```
import {MediaChange, ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";

const PRINT_MOBILE = 'print and (max-width: 600px)';

@Component({
   selector : 'responsive-component',
   template: `
      <div class="ad-content" *ngIf="media.isActive('xs')">
        Only shown if on mobile viewport sizes
      </div>
   `
})
export class MyDemo implements OnInit {
  constructor(public media: ObservableMedia) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.media.isActive('xs') && !this.media.isActive(PRINT_MOBILE)) {
       this.loadMobileContent();
    }
  }

  loadMobileContent() { /* .... */ }
}
```

- print and `(max-width: 600px)` is a mediaQuery for printing with mobile
  viewport sizes.
- `xs` is an alias associated with the mediaQuery for mobile viewport sizes.